# Excel JS Add-In - Shared Runtime Not Working

Tags: reactjs, office-js, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I'm trying to use the "Shared Runtime" to work with my Excel JS Add-In, but it's not working. Below are the docs that I have been reviewing. Below are screenshots of my project. It looks like I'm able to set an initial state but my custom function is not updating window.sharedState. I also tried using the Excel context object but that is not working either.

#### Documentation Links

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/share-data-and-events-between-custom-functions-and-the-task-pane-tutorial
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime

#### Project Screenshots

[My Excel Add-In Project (screenshot #1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhWR1.png)

[My Excel Add-In manifest.xml file (screenshot #2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrsI3.png)

Comment: Just a sanity check: Did you define a `Shared.Url` in the `<Resources>` section of the manifest?

Comment: It is defined in correctly in the <Resources> section. I believe that's why my initial state is being shared.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing the key parts of your project! Your screenshots are very helpful!

The fact that your custom function can read the shared state is a good sign.

The reason why your custom function is not changing the shared state may be because you are not providing a valid JSON. I see several problems with the values you are trying to set:

1. The `{ ... }` must be a literal, i.e. you cannot use variables inside. Thus, things like `{ oldVal: originalVal }` are not valid. If you want to use variables, you'll have to programmatically assign those values, e.g.

```
window.sharedState.test = {};
window.sharedState.test.oldVal = originalVal;
```

2. The literal `{ first, second }` is not valid - it doesn't adhere to the `property: value` pattern.
3. While JavaScript and TypeScript may allow unquoted property names, it is good to develop the habit of quoting them like `{ "something": 42 }`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried this out and no change. I think another red flag that something is off is that I also cannot access the Excel context object like the documentation shows. This feature plus the window.sharedState are part of the shared statement api based on the docs.

Comment: Or, if you want to start with a sample that doesn't require any building or deployment, put this manifest on a file share, and side-load it - https://github.com/OfficeDev/custom-functions/blob/master/addins/upgrade/upgrade_shared.xml. All of the code is in the same GitHub folder.

Comment: This sample is great. I checked it against my manifest file and everything looks good. Here is my manifest.xml file.

manifest.xml file link:
https://gist.github.com/thunter05/60dbb0cdca986aaeccd0f2e5e7afe17f

Comment: Your manifest does look good. It was even looking good yesterday. If it wasn't good, you'd see an installation error. I suspect your JavaScript is still bad. BTW, what do you see - an error or just no effect? Are you able to create a function that returns a constant number without any side effect, and can you use it in a formula?